# syntax error in accessing 2d register array in verilog code to synthesize in leonardo tool

Tags: arrays, caching, verilog, synthesis

I made a simple cache with verilog code in ISE tool, and used a 2d array of registers as my cache memory, simulating testbench on it in Modelsim done well and no syntax errors and no mistake in desires output signals, but in Leonardo tool when I tell Leonardo read it in library ams600nm it return syntax error near first line that I accessed my 2d array (cache), do you have any idea?

code:

```
module Cache(clk , wr
,din,adr,dout
);
input clk;
input wr;
input [3:0] din;
input [3:0] adr;
output [3:0] dout;
output hit;
 reg [8:0] cache [3:0];
 reg h;
 reg [3:0] out;
 initial
    begin
        ***cache[0][8] = 1'b0; -----here-----
        cache[1][8] = 1'b0; -----also here for sure-----
        cache[2][8] = 1'b0;
        cache[3][8] = 1'b0;***
    end
```

Comment: Please share the full error message. Also `hit` is defined as an output but not part of the port list; consider ANSI style header (ex: `module Cashe(input clk, input wr, input [3:0] din, input [3:0] adr, output reg [3:0] dout, output hit); reg [8:0] cashe [3:0];`)

Comment: hello, thank you for your comment, yes appropriate declaration of input and output is as you said, but in leonardo tool we should declare like this to be readable by leonardo -_- !!!
also error message in leonardo is "in line 15 syntax error near cache[0] [<-"

Comment: There are only two problems there (after removing your comments: 1) no *endmodule*, ho such thing as  'hit' used in the 'output' stateent. Please, do not insert non-compilable comments in your code (*** ---). They prevent from cut-n-paste.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have output `hit` in module port list.
2. You don't have `endmodule` keyword.
3. Some software allow to access only all bits in array's row. I don't have access to your software, so I can't test it, but you should try something like that:

```systemverilog
temp = cache[0];
cache[0] = {1'b 0, temp[7:0]};
```

This is equivalent to:

```systemverilog
cache[0][8] = 1'b0;
```

`temp`  should be declared as `reg [8:0] temp;` (same width as `cache`).

Comment: Tnx guys , yes hit wasn't declared and also enmodule because I cropped some parts of code.
I changed my way :) XD